# What software do you recommend for data visualization and graphing?

Tags: data-visualisation, data-extraction

I've been doing some graphs in excel for academic purposes, but I've ran into 2 main problems:

1. Excel doesn't have all the features I need
2. Designing graphs in excel is a pain in the ass

So I'm looking for graphing softwares that I could use instead in the future. Desirable features:

1. Allows me to retrieve data from my graph (like the coordinates of the highest point of a curve and the slope of a curve at a certain point)
2. Good graphics, good-looking graphs
3. Ease of use

The graphs I make are mainly of scientific nature, but presentation is also a key factor. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly better suited for [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Lots of suggestions in (and possibly duplicate of) https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/2191/30216

Answer (score 2):

Use mathematica. Does everything you need and more, much more. There is only one downside to mathematica and that is the price..But in academia its pretty cheap.